# What's the difference between Delete and Remove in a many-to-many relationship in CoolStorage

Tags: c#, .net, coolstorage

A many-to-many relationship has to methods to remove items: Delete and Remove. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information provided in your question:

Remove will remove the relationship between the parent and child objects while leaving the child objects existing.

Delete will remove the relationship between the parent and child objects and delete the child objects.

*UPDATE: I didn't know that the question refered to CoolStorage when I originally posted*